# Access Service Account key json using workload identity in GKE

Tags: .net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-kubernetes-engine

We are trying to resolve a issue to replace secrets with Workload identity.Below are more details.

We are accessing firestore and pubsub from a dot net core web api which is deployed in google kubernetes engine. We are using a secret for the appsettings json which is having all the service account keys, this secret is mounted to the deployment pods in a path and in code we were accessing the configurations by injecting the appsettings using the volume mount path of the secret json as a configuration provider. We use the json service account keys for creating the firestore builders and pubsub channel credentials like below.

API code using the service account json keys is shown as below:

**Pubsub**:

> _chanelCreds =
> GoogleCredential.FromJson(_pubSubSAJsoKey).ToChannelCredentials();

**Firestore**:

> _firestoreDb = new FirestoreDbBuilder
> {
> ProjectId = projectId,
> JsonCredentials = fireStoreServiceAccountJsonKey
> }.Build();

**Accessing the secret configuration in Program.cs:**

> public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>

> ```
>         Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
>             .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
>             {
>                 webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
>                 {
>                     config.AddJsonFile("**/secrets/api.secrets.json**").Build();
>                 });
>                 webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
>             });
> ```

**Part of the Deployment Yaml**

> ```
>     volumeMounts:
>     - name: appsettingssecret
>       mountPath: /secrets
>       readOnly: true
>   volumes:
>   - name: appsettingssecret
>     secret:
>       secretName: appsettingssecret
> ```

Now we have to switch to Workload identity but we are not sure on how to deal multiple service accounts in workload identity and also in code we need the json key of the service accounts so how to retrieve the key from workload identity.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I'm absolutely not a .Net developer but I can help on workload identities.*

Firstly, some concepts. Workload Identity on GKE create an interceptor. When the client library (Google Auth, PubSub or others) try to reach the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) to get the credentials, the request is intercepted and the credentials are generated based on the defined service account.

Therefore, you have to use the [ADC mechanism (Application Default Credential)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production). Don't specify any service account key file, let the library finding automatically the correct credentials according with the environment context.

If you have a look to the [.Net PubSub client library documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/), you never see an authentication with a service account key file, it uses the ADC. Same things for [Firestore](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore/)

---

That was for the authentication in your code. Now, how to deal with several service account.

On [Workload identity documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity), you can see how to create a KSA on a namespace and how to bind this KSA with a GSA. Thus, you simply have to define several KSA on a namespace and then, [add the correct KSA name in your deployment configuration](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity).

Comment: Thanks for replying, I will try this out but it seems answering my question.